# Unexpected token . on module.exports.function

Tags: javascript, express, mongoose

I'm trying to create a API register route, but when I try to use User.function - AddUser, which I created in model file it says that there is unexpected token `.`. Here is the code:

```js
router.post('/register', (req, res, next) => {
    let newUser = new User({
        username: req.body.username,
        name: req.body.name,
        email: req.body.email,
        password: req.body.password,
        photoUrl: req.body.photoUrl
    })

    User.addUser(newUser, (err, user) => {
        if (err) {
            res.send('Failed');
        } else {
            res.send('Registered');
        }
    });
});
```

Here is the model file code:

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const schema = mongoose.Schema;
const bcryptjs = require('bcryptjs');

const userSchema = new schema({
    username: { type: String, required: true },
    name: { type: String },
    email: { type: String, required: true },
    password: { type: String, required: true },
    photoUrl: { type: String }
});

const User = module.exports = mongoose.model('User', userSchema, 'users');

module.exports.addUser(newUser, callback) => {
    bcrypt.genSalt(10, (err, salt) => {
        bcrypt.hash(newUser.password, salt, (err, hash) => {
            if (err) throw err;
            newUser.password = hash;
            newUser.save(callback);
        });
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your model file code, add a `=` like following

```
module.exports.addUser = (newUser, callback) => {
    bcrypt.genSalt(10, (err, salt) => {
        bcrypt.hash(newUser.password, salt, (err, hash) => {
            if (err) throw err;
            newUser.password = hash;
            newUser.save(callback);
        });
    });
}
```